# IdentiyServer4 – API check if token has expired

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identityserver4

While doing some testing with IdentityServer4 I discovered a “strange” behavior.

*My API does not detect expired tokens.*

Setup:

- MVC project hosting IdentiyServer4
- A API project with a single test endpoint
- A cmd client

On IdentiyServer4-side the AccessTokenLifetime for my cmd client is set to 20 seconds.

When checking in my client I can see that the `exp` value of the JWT token is set correctly to `now` + 20 seconds.

The API accepts all calls from the client with a token (including expired tokens).

I would expect my API to only accept valid/ not yet expired tokens. But this is not the case.
Do I have to enable/add some validation component in my API project?

Here is the configuration of the API:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configure( IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env )
    {
        if ( env.IsDevelopment() )
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseMvc();
    }

    public void ConfigureServices( IServiceCollection services )
    {
        services.AddMvc();
        services.AddAuthorization();
        services
            .AddAuthentication( IdentityServerAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme )
            .AddIdentityServerAuthentication( options =>
            {
                options.Authority = "http://localhost:5000";
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                options.ApiName = "ApiPoc";
            } );
    }
}
```

IdentityServer-Host config:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configure( IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env )
    {
        if ( env.IsDevelopment() )
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();

        app.UseIdentityServer();
    }

    public void ConfigureServices( IServiceCollection services )
    {
        // IdentityServer 4
        services
            .AddIdentityServer()
            .AddDeveloperSigningCredential()
            .AddInMemoryIdentityResources( Config.GetIdentityResources() ) //check below
            .AddInMemoryApiResources( Config.GetApiResources() )
            .AddInMemoryClients( Config.GetClients() )
            .AddProfileService<ProfileService>();

        // Test - custom user repo
        services.AddTransient<IResourceOwnerPasswordValidator, ResourceOwnerPasswordValidator>();
        services.AddTransient<IProfileService, ProfileService>();
    }
}

public class Config
{
    public static IEnumerable<ApiResource> GetApiResources() =>
        new List<ApiResource>
        {
            new ApiResource( "ApiPoc", "API PoC" )
        };

    public static IEnumerable<Client> GetClients() => 
        new List<Client>
        {
            new Client
            {
                ClientId = "CmdClient",
                AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ResourceOwnerPassword,
                ClientSecrets =
                {
                    new Secret( "CmdClientSecret".Sha256() )
                },
                AllowedScopes = { "ApiPoc" },
                AccessTokenLifetime = 20,
                AccessTokenType = AccessTokenType.Jwt,
                SlidingRefreshTokenLifetime = 1296000
            }
        };

    public static IEnumerable<IdentityResource> GetIdentityResources() => 
        new List<IdentityResource>
        {
            new IdentityResources.OpenId(),
            new IdentityResources.Profile()
        };
}
```

Cmd client code:

```
private static async Task DoRequestInLoop()
{
    var client = new HttpClient();
    var disco = await client.GetDiscoveryDocumentAsync( "http://localhost:5000" ).ConfigureAwait( false );
    if ( disco.IsError )
    {
        Console.WriteLine( $"Failed to get discovery document: {disco.Error}" );
        return;
    }

    var tokenResponse = await client.RequestPasswordTokenAsync( new PasswordTokenRequest
                                                                {
                                                                    Address = disco.TokenEndpoint,
                                                                    ClientId = "CmdClient",
                                                                    ClientSecret = "CmdClientSecret",
                                                                    Scope = "ApiPoc",
                                                                    Password = "user",
                                                                    UserName = "password",
                                                                    Parameters = new Dictionary<String, String>
                                                                    {
                                                                        { "UserGroup", "A_Admin" },
                                                                        { "Tenant", "A" }
                                                                    }
                                                                },
                                                                CancellationToken.None ).ConfigureAwait( false );
    if ( tokenResponse.IsError )
    {
        Console.WriteLine( $"Failed to obtain token: {tokenResponse.Error}." );
        return;
    }

    var json = tokenResponse.Json.ToString();
    client.SetBearerToken( tokenResponse.AccessToken );
    Console.WriteLine( $"Token: {json}" );

    while ( !_loopCanceled )
    {
        var response = await client.GetAsync( "http://localhost:5001/api/Values" ).ConfigureAwait( false );
        Console.WriteLine( !response.IsSuccessStatusCode ? $"Request failed with status code {response.StatusCode}" : "Request successful." );
        await Task.Delay( 22000 ).ConfigureAwait( false );
    }
}
```

Token received by the client from the IdentityServer (you can see it is valid for only 20 seconds, which is correct)

```
{
  "nbf": 1546243372,
  "exp": 1546243392,
  "iss": "http://localhost:5000",
  "aud": [
    "http://localhost:5000/resources",
    "ApiPoc"
  ],
  "client_id": "CmdClient",
  "sub": "1",
  "auth_time": 1546243372,
  "idp": "local",
  "SomeClaim": "Claim",
  "scope": [
    "ApiPoc"
  ],
  "amr": [
    "custom"
  ]
}
```

Comment: when you debug this whats the values you get vs what you expect?

Comment: you really shouldn't be using GrantTypes.ResourceOwnerPassword

Comment: Have a look into the __ClockSkew__ configuration option in your API.  It usually defaults to 5 minutes and would explain what you are seeing i.e. it will still accept tokens for 5 minutes after expiry.

Comment: @SimonPrice As far as I can tell, all “values” are correct. The API just ignores the expires value. What should I inspect during debugging?

Comment: @DaImTo I know but my app won’t be able to support something like the Implicit type.

Comment: @Brad I thought about something like this… but I let it run for hours and it still did accept the token.

Comment: @Brad Setting the JwtValidationClockSkew property manually `options.JwtValidationClockSkew = TimeSpan.FromSeconds( 10 );` fixed the validation. If you add this a answer a will accept it.

Comment: Not answering your question but just pointing also what DalmTo said. If you are going to have a case like that in real world (machine-to-machine, without user interaction) you should be looking at the client_credentials flow: https://identitymodel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/client/token.html#requesting-a-token-using-the-client-credentials-grant-type

Comment: It seems that the app needs 'offline access' in order to access the user's resource. The flow should be that the user logs in once, gives consent for offline_access and then the client stores the refresh token in a safe place. This way the app remains ignorant of the users credentials, but is able to login on behalf of the user. Refresh tokens are supported in hybrid, authorization code, device flow and resource owner password flows: http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/topics/grant_types.html#refresh-tokens. Then it should be a small step to implement another flow.